# Function to echo css in the head and also include file.php inside the body

Tags: php, php-include

I am trying to create a function in my sitewide-variables.php that will echo some additional css (which doesn't need to be included with every page) in the head of the page and at the same time to include file.php (that uses the css needed in the head) inside the body section of the page if the page is number 1 for instance, obviously if the page is number 2 than nothing has to be echoed or included at all.

something similar to the following

```
<head><?php include("/variables/sitewide-variables.php"); ?>
<link href="css/style_new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<?php $number = 1; echo $css?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $number = 1; include $file.php?>
</body>
```

My understanding of this is to create something similar to the following inside the sitewide-variables.php

```
<?php 
$css[$number] = 'selected';
echo isset($css[1]) ? $css['some css code'] : '' 
?>
```

and this is as far as I can go with it.

I know that all above might simply be one huge mistake, but I hope that this is enough to explain what I am actually trying to achieve.

As you can probably guess, my knowledge of php is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit redundant, why not simply have a preset array of css bits:

```
$css = array(
   'style1' => '...',
   'style2' => '...',
   ...
);
```

as your "css storage", and then in the appropriate places of your pages, you just do

```
echo $css['styleX'];
```

without needing to set MORE global variables to access OTHER global variables.

Comment: the reason is that particular css is very short and only needed to position slider on the home page and therefore I see no real reason for additional css files. hope it makes sense!

Comment: I have edited my question to show that my main css file is included with every page and that additional css I was talking about is only needed for page 1 (meaning home page only)

Comment: doesn't take much to just create a new class and apply that to whatever elements you need, rather than dynamically inserting inline css all over.

Comment: pagespeed suggests to reduce css and therefore I kinda thought that this would actually be helpful in my situation

Answer (score 0):

Would this fix your problem?

```
<head>
<?php include("/variables/sitewide-variables.php"); ?>
<link href="css/style_new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<?php echo $css?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include ('file.php'); ?>
</body>
```

Then in your 'sitewide-variables.php' file:

```
$css = "<style> ['insert css code here'] </style>";
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to avoid, instead I am trying to create a function that will output 2 variables, one of which will contain css and another will contain file that need to be included

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you have a variable with a number and depending of this number you want to add a css in your header.

You can use various ways for it, like IF or SWITCH function.
Regarding the way you want to handle it, i would add a function inside "sitewide-variables.php" like this one :

```
function mycss($number) {
    switch($number) {
        case 1 : $css = ' here goes css instructions for page 1 '; break;
        case 2 : $css = ' here goes css instructions for page 2 '; break;
        default : $css = ''; break; // no page, no css
    }
    return $css;
}
```

This function will return a string with your CSS, so inside your page you can add this :

```
<head><?php $number = 1; include("/variables/sitewide-variables.php"); ?>
<link href="css/style_new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<?php echo mycss($number); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: something similar but with 2 variables where I can set one to include css and another to include file.php under condition set by the page number, in my case number 1 and not otherwise.

Comment: I have just edited my code, can you please have a look at it, if yo u have time

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to the sitewide-variables.php

```
if ($number = 1)
    {$slider_css = '<style>
/* ~~ Slider ~~ */
.slider_panel {height:270px;margin-top:11px;clear:both;}
.slider {width:950px; height:250px; padding-top:10px;overflow:hidden;}
#fader {width:950px;height:250px;}
#fader ul {list-style:none;margin:0px;padding:0px;height:215px;width:950px;}
#fader ul li {width:950px;height:250px;display:none;}
#fader ul li.active {display:block;}
#faderNav {position:relative;float:right;margin-right:20px;width:150px;}
#faderNav a {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;-o-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;display:block; float:left;height: 15px;margin: 10px 4px;width: 15px;outline:none;}
#faderNav a.active {background:#06222e;}
</style>';
$slider = $getPath . '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/trial/includes/top_slider.php';}
     else
     {$slider_css = ' ';
     $slider = ' ';}
```

and the following to every page on my site

```
<head><?php $number = 1; include("/variables/sitewide-variables.php"); ?>
<link href="css/style_new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<?php echo $slider_css?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include $slider ?>
</body>
```

and it all started to work in the way I needed.

Thanks to all, who has tried to help me!!!